# Cordova application white screen - "crash"

Tags: reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

We have a hybrid mobile app based on Cordova, ReactJS and Tyepscript.

The app seems to "crash" for some users for no apparent reason.

"Crash" meaning showing a white screen that's essentially the index.html with the message "Critical ERROR - CLICK HERE TO EMAIL SUPPORT", the emails we receive from users is the only way we know about those crashes.

We use Sentry for our error reporting but it doesn't show anything that might point to those crashes.

We think that the problem might be with some of our Cordova plugins not playing nicely together, we have the following plugins installed: (From package.json)

`"cordova": "6.5.0",
"cordova-android": "6.4.0",
"cordova-ios": "4.4.0",
"cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "2.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "2.4.1",
"cordova-plugin-code-push": "1.9.8-beta",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.6",
"cordova-plugin-dialogs": "1.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.6.3",
"cordova-plugin-firebase": "0.1.24",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "2.4.3",
"cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-keyboard": "1.1.5",
"cordova-plugin-mixpanel": "4.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "2.3.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "3.2.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.1",
"cordova-plugin-vibration": "2.1.5",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.2",
"cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-zip": "3.1.0"`

We have tried updating and downgrading some of them with little success.
Any ideas as to what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Every times i had a white screen on my cordova app, it was a syntax error in my code

Comment: Have you added a plugin recently ? Try to use this plugin : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release It's like a plugin orchestra conductor's

Comment: @Djiggy we use Typescript and a very strict linter so that seems unlikely.

Comment: @EnzoBLANCHON This had started happening after one of the developers made a few big changes to the plugins, but I had since reverted all the version back to their original version.
He might have added a few plugins that I had forgot about, I'll check and edit the question.